# Is Krishna Everything?

Tags: krishna

I have a doubt that's troubling me from every direction. It is said that there's god in everyone and every action that is going to take place let it be even as small as blinking is predefined somewhere. So is it that all the characters in Mahabharata, Ramayana, the people that have lived till now, the people living now, every animal, every living/non-living thing are all just one God(**Krishna**) doing everything? And he too already knows the outcome of a certain situation and still becomes a part of it.

Comment: Yes. Just as example water appearing as the wave. Wave is like a form but still its water. Underlying reality for everything is Krishna who himself thru his Yogamaya appears as this Universe. Who are we then? The jeeva who aren't aware of the underlying reality and assume ourself to be doer.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti then why all the pain and suffering? Why does God himself have to suffer through us? And why should i believe this theory: That God is in everyone? So you mean that god raped himself whenever such incidents take place?

Comment: Read my last line.  "The jeeva who aren't aware of the underlying reality and assume ourself to be doer" = Its this jeeva who is under maya and suffering. its this jeeva which suffering karmas. Who realizes Krishna alone IS, he becomes pure and is liberated from samsara

Comment: Also think in this angle deeply. If water appearing as wave, is Water in bondage and any kind of attachment with wave? Same way, Krishna is never in bondage. Then find who is in bondage. That ll enlighten you.

Comment: Atman was or is never in bondage, its the adhyasa/superimposition. Just like while playing a game, many times a player forgets reality and gets attached to the game but when the game's character dies, the player remains still alive, similarly in the Maya matrix, jivatmas are given environment to learn but never perish in reality(gist of Geeta) but majority never get bored of cyclic reincarnation because of attractive Maya.

Comment: How did you came to the conclusion that Krishna is god? Are you a vaishnava?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, Krishna says in the Gita (Swami Nikhilananda translator):

> 11.32 *The Lord said*: I am mighty, world destroying Time, now engaged here in slaying these men. Even without you [Arjuna], all these warriors standing arrayed in the opposing armies shall not live.
>
> 11.33 Therefore stand up and win glory; conquer your enemies and enjoy an opulent kingdom. By Me and none other have they already been slain; be an instrument only, O Arjuna.

and in Gita 7.7, Krishna says:

> There exists nothing whatever higher than I am, O Dhanajaya. All is strung on Me as a row of gems on a thread.

and in Gita 18.61:

> The Lord dwells in the hearts of all beings, O Arjuna, and by His maya causes them to revolve as though mounted on a machine.

Answer (score 3):

I am the source of all material and spiritual worlds. Everything emanates from Me.

Krishna claims he’s the source of everything. Has anybody ever checked up on that? Apparently yes. Arjuna asked Him to show exactly how that was true, and He showed the vishva rupa. How do we know He did? And what was it? It was a form that demonstrated that all of existence was contained within Him. What would that look like? The description is in Bhagavad-gita:

> If hundreds of thousands of suns were to rise at once into the sky, their radiance might resemble the effulgence of the Supreme Person in that universal form. At that time Arjuna could see in the universal form of the Lord the unlimited expansions of the universe situated inone place although divided into many, many thousands.

Sounds like a reasonable description, even if it is a mind-blowing idea. Arjuna’s mind was blown, by the way. He had a hard time keeping his composure while Krishna was making His grand display:

> O all-pervading Viṣṇu, seeing You with Your many radiant colors touching the sky, Your gaping mouths, and Your great glowing eyes, my mind is perturbed by fear. I can no longer maintain my steadiness or equilibrium of mind. O Lord of lords, O refuge of the worlds, please be gracious to me. I cannot keep my balance seeing thus Your blazing deathlike faces and awful teeth. In all directions I am bewildered.

After Krishna again withdrew the vision, Arjuna again saw Krishna the way he preferred to see Him, as a person, as his friend, the person he knew:

> When Arjuna thus saw Kṛṣṇa in His original form, he said: O Janārdana, seeing this humanlike form, so very beautiful, I am now composed in mind, and I am restored to my original nature.

After all, how do you have a relationship with “everything?” People have relationships with each other. You can’t have a valid, satisfying emotional exchange with a pile of stuff. You can look in awe at something big like the sky or the ocean or the mountains or the Grand Canyon, but relationships are for people to have with other people. You can’t have lunch with the Grand Canyon. You can have lunch at the Grand Canyon.

[source](http://www.krishna.com/how-krishna-everything-0)